# \include{} and bibtex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, include

I can't make `\include{}` and BibTeX work together for some reasons. The bibliography is displayed but not the references. They all appear with **?**. What is wrong with me?

Here is my code :

```
\includeonly{intro}

\begin{document}

\include{intro}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\bibliography{intro_conclu}

\end{document}
```

Yet, when I do not use include it works perfectly :

\includeonly{intro}

```
\begin{document}
```

my intro written here

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\bibliography{intro_conclu}

\end{document}
```

and even when I use input instead of include, references are updated correctly

Comment: You should follow the guidelines in [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/5764).

Comment: Welcome! And no. That is not normal. `\include{}` should work without `\includeonly{}`. `\includeonly{}` is not used for final compilation in any case.

Comment: well I have followed the recommandation and it works perfectly when I don't use include. But with include it does not seem to be working